# global usings and .NET Standard 2.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-standard

I recently recognized that I can use the C# 10 feature *file-scoped namespaces* in .NET Standard 2.0 projects as well by setting `<LangVersion>10</LangVersion>` in the `csproj` file.

However, *global usings* don't work that way, I'm getting compiler errors due to missing using statements.

Are there any tweaks so that I can use *global usings* in a .NET Standard 2.0 library as well?

Comment: Can provide your csproj file?

Comment: This is working for me, I set LangVersion to 10 and have a file with just my global usings in and it compiles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why it doesn't work with a separated .cs file. However, a workaround that works is using the MSBuild syntax. In your `.csproj` you can add the following:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

There are some keywords you can use - like `Alias` or `Static` -, as you would do in a normal .cs file.

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="Test.Namespace" Alias="Domain" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

And then in your code, you can do the following:

```
namespace Test.Namespace 
{
    public class TestClass {}
}

namespace Another.Namespace
{
    new Domain.TestClass();
}
```

If it helps, I found this information in the following [blog post](https://www.daveabrock.com/2021/10/21/csharp-10-global-usings/).

Comment: Thanks man, that's all I need! 