# Why does StyleCopAnalyzers think that global usings should be declared within a namespace, when such syntax is not possible?

Tags: c#, .net, namespaces, stylecop, using-directives

I am creating a [NUnit](https://nunit.org/) test project and in the creation of that, MS Visual Studio has created a file called *Usings.cs* with the line

```
global using NUnit.Framework;
```

which tells the project to include the NUnit framework in every file.

I have been running [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) over this test project, and it keeps reporting

> SA1200: Using directive should appear within a namespace declaration.

However, when I put the `global using` within a namespace declaration

```
namespace TestProject
{
    global using NUnit.Framework;
}
```

I get the error

> CS8914: A global using directive cannot be used in a namespace declaration.

What is the correct approach? Should I use the *Usings.cs* file with `global usings`?

Comment: I would create a new c# file for that. I think theres also csproj items you can use

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71305266/global-usings-and-net-standard-2-0

Comment: it appears Stylecop is also out of date

Comment: Putting `<Using Include="NUnit.Framework" />` in the .csproj file works! However with the up-t-to-date [StyleCopAnalyzers](https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers) the same problem remains when using the separate c# file

Answer (score 1):

In your .csproj add the following lines

```
 <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="NUnit.Framework" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: This is only a workaround, and not the answer to the question why StyleCopAnalyzers does not allow me to use `global usings`, or how to use `global usings` while using StyleCopAnalyzers

Comment: In C# 10.0 you can use Global Usings.

and C# 10.0 released with NET 6.0. Can you please tell me your c# version?

Comment: I am using .NET 6.0, so that is C# 10.0

Comment: did you remove remove <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings> from .csproj file?

Comment: Yes, but what does that have to do with the NUnit framework?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the default may have changed.  The fix involves updating your editor config file (.editorconfig) that should be in the same directory as your solution.

Look for the following

- csharp_using_directive_placement
- dotnet_diagnostic.SA1200.severity

You want them to look like

```
csharp_using_directive_placement = outside_namespace
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1200.severity = None
```

or just delete csharp_using_directive_placement to get the default behavior

```
dotnet_diagnostic.SA1200.severity = None
```

In my project, `csharp_using_directive_placement` was set to inside_namespace, and this is impossible in a global using file.